# Check subset of an element of a set of sets

Tags: set, subset

Assume a set of sets of numbers S. Given a new set of numbers s, I would like to know whether s is a subset of an element in S. What would be an efficient way to perform this check? For instance, what would be a suitable data structure to store the set of sets of numbers S or procedure to efficiently check whether s is a subset of some element in S?